# Why is Scala version added to URL when no %% used in libraryDependencies?

Tags: sbt

I am trying to change a dependency in [Tormenta project](https://github.com/twitter/tormenta/blob/develop/project/Build.scala#L135) from

```
libraryDependencies += "storm" % "storm-kafka" % "0.9.0-wip6-scala292-multischeme"
```

to

```
libraryDependencies += "net.wurstmeister.storm" % "storm-kafka-0.8-plus" % "0.4.0"
```

The build is failing because sbt is trying to download  http://clojars.org/repo/net/wurstmeister/storm/storm-kafka-0.8-plus**_2.9.2**/0.4.0/storm-kafka-0.8-plus-0.4.0.jar even though I don't specify `%%` in `libraryDependencies`.

Why is sbt appending `_2.9.2` to the artifact to be downloaded?!

Comment: Could you attach the outputs of `sbt --version` and `sbt about`? Could you show `build.sbt` (or any other build definitions you may have in the project)?

Comment: sbt --version
sbt launcher version 0.13.0

Comment: I cloned the project from github on two different computers and ran into the same issue. I havent modified any other file and all other build file are in here https://github.com/twitter/tormenta/tree/develop/project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pom.xml` from the [Clojars Repository](http://clojars.org/repo/net/wurstmeister/storm/storm-kafka-0.8-plus/0.4.0/storm-kafka-0.8-plus-0.4.0.pom) contains following entries:

```
<properties>
  <scalaVersion>2.9.2</scalaVersion>
  <kafkaArtifact>kafka_2.9.2</kafkaArtifact>
  <envClassifier/>
</properties>
```

during resolving Ivy will use following pattern for computing download URL

```
[organisation]/[module](_[scalaVersion])(_[sbtVersion])/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

and it will substitute `[scalaVersion]` with the values read from the `pom.xml`. Hence the invalid URL and the error.

#### Edit

As I've promised promised the detailed description what happens:

Ivy will download POM of the library. 
Somewhere in the process of downloading dependencies, Ivy will call [MyModuleDescriptorProvider#provideModule](https://github.com/apache/ivy/blob/2.3.0/src/java/org/apache/ivy/core/cache/DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java#L712). The function will return `ModuleDescriptor` obtained by parsing already downloaded POM file.

To do that Ivy calls [CustomPomParser#parseDescriptor](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/CustomPomParser.scala#L18). After some series of calls we arrive at [CustomPomParser#defaultTransformImpl](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/CustomPomParser.scala#L70), which first line is `val properties = getPomProperties(md)`.

The resulting `properties` contain the Scala version property defined in the POM file. The properties are stored in the `ModuleDescriptor` as an extra module attributes.

Later when the download URL is built, the pattern I have mentioned previously is used. The place holders, are substituted in a method [IvyPatternHelper.subsitute](https://github.com/apache/ivy/blob/2.3.0/src/java/org/apache/ivy/core/IvyPatternHelper.java#L127). Arguments to the method contain the parsed attributes and the substitution leads to the faulty URL.

Comment: I'd say the first part of the answer's correct since these properties are indeed used in `pom.xml`, but Ivy will only read the dependencies (that use the properties) and download them. `[scalaVersion]` is in no way affected by the properties since they are exclusively used by `pom.xml`. I would only add a note about the dependency with `kafkaArtifact` substituted.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski perchaps my wording was ambiguous, as I didn't mean resolving transitive dependencies, but download URL (edited my answer). I still claim though that those properties matter. I'll update the answer later with more details on the flow.

Comment: @lpiepiora thanks for identifying the problem! Do you know anyways I can tell SBT/Ivy not to append scalaVersion for this artifact as it is causing the build to fail :-(

Comment: @MansoorAshraf You could declare your dependency using explicit URL http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#explicit-url

Comment: @JacekLaskowski please find the explanation of how those properties end up in the URL. I know it's a bit chaotic, but I was trying to only focus on the key points.